# Traceroute: destination IP-address returned for all but first hop. (Debian 9.11)

Tags: networking, debian, traceroute, icmp

At some point in the past year, Traceroute behavior changed. Was working correctly prior.
(Debian v9.11 Traceroute 1:2.1.0-2) 
Now, first traceroute result, my gateway, is correct, but all the intermediate hops list the destination ip address rather than the intermediate host. My perimeter firewall explicitly permits ICMP any.

Localhost firewall:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Traceroute results:

```
shughes@skht5d:~$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  pfSense.abc.example.com (192.168.11.1)  3.222 ms  3.200 ms  3.190 ms
 2  * * *
 3  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  11.662 ms  11.656 ms  11.616 ms
 4  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  14.003 ms  16.191 ms  16.177 ms
 5  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  14.002 ms  13.981 ms  16.121 ms
 6  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  22.640 ms  16.258 ms  19.028 ms
 7  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  25.339 ms  20.188 ms  20.170 ms
 8  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  27.407 ms  25.020 ms  27.858 ms
 9  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  24.951 ms  24.472 ms  24.456 ms
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  23.790 ms  21.811 ms  24.017 ms
11  * * dns.google (8.8.8.8)  20.639 ms
12  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  21.437 ms  23.536 ms  22.119 ms
13  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  21.429 ms  21.181 ms  21.207 ms
shughes@skht5d:~$ 

shughes@skht5d:~$ traceroute a2hosting.com
traceroute to a2hosting.com (104.18.131.225), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  pfSense.abc.example.com (192.168.11.1)  11.043 ms  11.001 ms  11.006 ms
 2  * * *
 3  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  18.531 ms  18.527 ms  18.519 ms
 4  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  18.514 ms  18.508 ms  18.493 ms
 5  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  18.472 ms  18.476 ms  18.451 ms
 6  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  30.552 ms  30.868 ms  26.008 ms
 7  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  26.017 ms  30.792 ms  30.755 ms
 8  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  41.155 ms  30.765 ms  30.757 ms
 9  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  30.722 ms  30.714 ms  30.707 ms
10  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  30.703 ms  29.137 ms  28.252 ms
11  104.18.131.225 (104.18.131.225)  28.202 ms  29.162 ms  29.151 ms
shughes@skht5d:~$
```

Comment: What do you get from `traceroute --icmp`? Note that Linux traceroute defaults to using UDP on high-numbered ports, unlike Windows tracert.

Comment: Progress! Thanks for the insight.
traceroute --icmp works as expected.  
Problem appears to be pfSense, though a "permit IPv4 UDP any any" did not fix it.
When using my phone hot-spot both UDP and ICMP methods work as expected.

Comment: Are you sure pfSense is producing these unwanted replies? Have you checked using tcpdump on both its interfaces?

Comment: Ah!  But, an ICMP reply to a UDP traceroute packet may not be seen as related. I will add the appropriate WAN rule and test again.

Comment: Traceroute replies are actually ICMP _error_ messages, so they include enough of the original UDP packet to identify as "related" – at least in any decent firewall. But the problem you're seeing isn't that the replies do not arrive – it's that the replies arrive "from" the wrong source IP address.

Comment: Correct.  I see in Wireshark they are shown as related. Packet capture (using pfSense capture) on the WAN show ICMP Time-to-live exceeded from intermediate hosts (expected result). Capture on LAN also shows ICMP Time-to-live exceeded packets, but Source-IP is always listed as the final destination IP.

Comment: This article says the problem occurs when using Limiters. https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/9263
Confirmed: fixed when I disable Limiters.